# ADO .Net Autogenerating models with imports after namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

Problem is for database first  - every model that is generated reports errors. And all imports are added after namespace. I can cut/paste it before namespace, but if I want to update from table from DB - same code error is generated. I never had this problem before.

```
namespace Test_WebApi
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class AspNetRoles
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public AspNetRoles()
        {
            this.AspNetRoleClaims = new HashSet<AspNetRoleClaims>();
            this.AspNetUsers = new HashSet<AspNetUsers>();
        }

        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string NormalizedName { get; set; }
        public string ConcurrencyStamp { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<AspNetRoleClaims> AspNetRoleClaims { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<AspNetUsers> AspNetUsers { get; set; }
    }
```

All models are generated with this error including DbContext class.

Comment: `every model that is generated reports errors` `All models are generated with this error` What's the error?

Comment: No imports, I must cut/paste imports before namespace. Obviously